# eToro vs interactive investor

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, international

I live in the UK and would be interested to learn investing online. I've yet to discover my style but I'd prefer to invest longer term based on international/sector macros. So far I only know a few platforms (eg. eToro and Interactive Investor).

However simply Googling I find it hard to compare the platforms. Can someone review / compare / introduce a platform to me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're a long term investor, IMO, the platform isn't going to matter much.  Your primary concern should be low commissions.

If they offer it, the best way to get a feel for a platform is to open a demo account.

Here are a few of the high and low lights of Interactive Brokers (U.S.):

Ultra low per share/contract commission rate which enables scaling in and out of positions without penalty.  If you trade larger blocks of shares, you're better off at a fixed fee broker.  Free assignment and exercise for options.

Low margin rates and portfolio margin.

News is so so.  No comparison with real time Dow Jones news

They offer a DDE connection which enables Excel to be linked to the platform in real time. That's a big plus for me.

I haven't had problems with customer service and tech support but many users have complaints.

The charting is acceptable.

The option analytics are adequate.  The best broker for this is ThinkOrSwim.

Lots of trading algos for placing more complex buy and stop orders.

The platform isn't an easy one.  For simple buying and sell of equities, it's easy.  For more complex trading (option combos, etc.), it takes a bit of effort to master.  If you need hand holding, this one probably isn't for you.  If you know what you're doing, fast execution with immediate reports.